# I have a Guitar with bridge without Pins. How can I change strings?

Tags: guitar, strings, bridge

[image]Strings need to be changed on Guitar with Bridge without pins

Comment: A picture of the bridge would help. Are the old strings still on it?

Comment: Do you have a classical guitar with nylon strings or a steel string guitar with a pinless bridge such as a Takamine or Breedlove?

Comment: Yes, I still have old strings on it. I am new to guitar. So I don't want to take risk, Actually I posted a pic, but don't know what happened here. I have purchased Lanjian Acoustic Guitar Black. Steel Strings. Since I am new and cant afford much I had purchased a cheap one. Its almost one year and I practice almost everyday for 1hr, the sound is quite poor now. And How to post a picture here?

Comment: Find the ball ends. They are either under what is shown here, which will be a wedge pointing to the left, which is trivial, or else they are inside the instrument, so you have to insert through the sound hole.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a classical guitar with a bridge like the one pictured below -  you have to tie them a knot at the bridge.

[image]

I [found](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-attach-a-nylon-string-to-the-bridge-of-an-a.html) some tutorial explaining how to do it.

- Remove the old string (if you haven't already).
- Pass one end of the new string through the hole in the top of the bridge, in the direction away from the soundhole. Leave about 1-1/2 inches sticking out the rear of the hole.
- Secure the string by bringing the short end over the bridge and passing it under the long part of the string.
- Then pass the short end under, over, and then under itself, on the top of the bridge.
- Pull on the long end of the string with one hand and move the knot with the other to remove excess slack and cause the knot to lie flat against the bridge.

If you have a pinless bridge on a steel string guitar such as those found on many Breedlove guitars and some Takamine guitars, you pull the strings through the hole being sure to protect your guitar's finish from the steel strings in the process.  Here is a YouTube video showing how to do this on a pinless bridge for steel string guitar.

Comment: This is a great answer assuming the bridge in question is this type (which is a good bet). I wonder if it's a steel-string bridge with the pins lost or missing, though. If the asker clarifies and it's this type of bridge you'll get my vote.

Comment: Hey I was going to do a separate answer to explain how to change strings on a pinless bridge but it was easier to edit your answer than type a new one.  I am upvoting your answer now that it covers BOTH scenarios.  I had a Breedlove with pinless bridge.  I like the concept for steel string guitars.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I had an old Fender acoustic where most of the bridge pin heads broke off with the strings on it.  I had to cut the old strings and reach into the soundhole and tap them out from underneath before installing the new bridge pins.  Cheap made in China Fender with plastic bridge pins.  I keep at least one extra bridge pin in every guitar case.